# Can't figure out why index is out of bound for IO file

Tags: java, io, indexoutofboundsexception

This program reads from card.raw and creates a jpg. I could create the first image sucessfully, but I can't seem to figure out why i get an index out of bound error for the second image

```
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;
  import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
  import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;

  public class Recoverytst {
     public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
           FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("card.raw");
           FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("1.jpg");
           byte[] fileContent = new byte[512];

           while (fs.read(fileContent) != -1) {
           os.write(fileContent);
        }
          fs.close();
          os.close();
    }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
           System.out.println("Error " + ioe.getMessage());
   }

try {
  FileInputStream fs2 = new FileInputStream("card.raw");
  FileOutputStream os2 = new FileOutputStream("2.jpg");
  byte[] fileContent2 = new byte[512];

  while (fs2.read(fileContent2) != -1) {
```

Cant figure out why i get index out of bound error over here for the line below

```
    os2.write(fileContent2,513,512);
  }
  fs2.close();
  os2.close();
}
catch(IOException ioe) {
  System.out.println("Error " + ioe.getMessage());
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
os2.write(fileContent2,513,512);
```

What this means is every time it executes, you are trying to write 512 bytes from the array skipping 513 bytes but the array is only 512 bytes long. So it won't fit.

Try this..

```
File file = new File("path to card.raw");
long len = file.length();

byte[] fileContent = new byte[len];
fs2.read(fileContent);
```

After that use

```
os2.write(fileContent2,513,512);
```

out side the loop only once. It will write 512 bytes of data starting from the 513 byte.

Comment: Could you reccomend a better way for me to write it then? I'm new to programming

Comment: Set the offset to 0 (second argument.)

Comment: That will just make me get the first image again right? I want to get the second image in card.raw

Comment: Then you should store all the data from card.raw in 1 byte array. Then use that single byte array and apply the offset.

Comment: could you explain with a small piece of code/ (pseudo code)? I'm a little lost with the terminology

Answer (score 0):

This is normal in the way that you chose an arbitrary size of the byte array (512) and the image file size must be bigger than 512.

Comment: Could you give me some direction in getting the 2nd image then?

Comment: Take the size as being 3000 for example and test your program. Then if it works you can get the size of the image file with a cleaner way by using the length() method on the file.